# How to change lat/lng coordinates in pixel in Mapbox-gl-js inside Expression?

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

Good day!

I want to create an expression in Mapbox-gl-js for circle-radius. The challenge is circle-radius takes value in pixel but I have geographical coordinates(lat/lng).

When I try to use Map.project inside expression below(doesn't work):

```
['*',
            2,
            [
                '*',
                ['pi'],
                [
                    '-',
                    map.project(['get', 'p1'])[0], //<--doesn't work
                    map.project(['get', 'p2'])[0]  //<--doesn't work
                ]
            ]
]
```

```
const layer: mapboxgl.Layer = {
        'id': seatLayerName,
        'type': "circle",
        'source': 'maine',
        'paint': {
            "circle-radius": [
             'interpolate',
             ['exponential', 2],
             ['zoom'],
             5,
             ...//code
             13,
            ['*', 2, ['*', ['pi'], ['-', ['get', 'p1'], ['get', 'p2']]]] //<-- How to use map.project here
           ]
        }
    };
```

Geojson:

```
{
            "type": "FeatureCollection",
            "features": [
                {
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "geometry": {
                        "type": "Point",
                        "coordinates": [
                            8.156983852386475,
                            -4.0492925407532
                        ]
                    },
                    "properties": {
                        p1: [8.156983852386475, -4.0492925407532], //<-- point 1 lat/lng
                        p2: [8.176983852386475, -4.0492925407532]  //<-- point 2 lat/lng
                    }
                },
              ....
]
}
```

Attaching a screenshot, which I want to achieve creating an expression:
[image]

Mapbox provides [map.project](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#project) method to convert lat/lng to the pixel.

But how can I use this inside an expression?

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do. If your data is in pixel coordinates, what does this negative value (`-4.049....`) represent? A value off the top of your map? Why do you have pixel values fo geographic data anyway?

Comment: Hey @SteveBennett p1 and p2 inside properties are geographical coordinates ([8.156983852386475, -4.0492925407532]) lat/lng. I am trying to convert them into pixel using `.project` method but not able to do so.

Comment: The idea behind converting lat/lng to the pixel is to calculate the circle radius. So when I try to covert Map.project and pass ['get', 'p1'] as args. The expression doesn't fetched value from(['get', 'p1']), instead pass ['get', 'p1'] as string in args.

Comment: I still don't understand what you're trying to achieve. What is the radius meant to be?

Comment: Attached a screenshot in the description of what I really wanted to achieve in expression.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just provide the radius in the geojson? Seems you are going about this very indirectly.

Comment: The reason is when map zoom-in/zoom-out size of the circle radius should change from small(when the complete map is visible) to large(the more zoomed in-state). Hence the radius change's from minZoom to maxZoom and we cannot fix(Hard-code) the radius in geojson(As we don't know the value which would fit the radius across zoom level).     
Also, this approach is working perfectly if I pass the distance between p1 and p1 initially(calculation is done beforehand). 
But I am not able to access Map.project inside an expression(This is the only pain I am facing)